# How to plot a plane that is parallel to the z-axis in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, geometry, gnuplot, plane

When plotting a plane that is not parallel to the z-axis, one can simply solve the equation with respect to z and plot it as a function of x and y using splot. When plotting the plane `x+y+z=1` for example one can just use `z(x, y)=1-x-y` and then `splot z(x, y)`.

But how can I plot the plane `x+y=1` in gnuplot when there is no function `z(x, y)` that describes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the parametric mode to plot such a plane:

```
set parametric
splot 2 - u, u, v w l
```

[image]

For the records, here's the full code to generate the above plot:

```
set ticslevel 0
set xzeroaxis
set yzeroaxis
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
set zlabel 'z'
set autoscale fix
set parametric
splot 2 - u, u, v w l
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For everyone reading this i will present the solution for the `x+y=1` problem:

Set x or y equal to u. I will choose x. This means that `x=u`, `y=1-u` and `z=v` as u and v are the free parameters. Therefore the command that plots the plane `x+y=1` is `splot u, 1-u, v`.